# Is it possible to use zod schema as type and constrain it?

Tags: typescript, constraints, typescript-generics, zod

I have few Zod schemas. Let's call them Schema1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. I am trying to create a function that should allow only schemas 1 and 2 as its second parameter

```js
function someFunc(parameter1: any, schema: ???) {
  schema.parse(.....)
  // And do something else
}
```

I know I could type the schema in the function as `z.ZodTypeAny`, but then that would allow all the schemas to be passed into the function. Is there a way to constrain the schema parameter so that it would only allow certain type of schemas passed into the function?

Comment: function someFunc(parameter1: any, schema: typeof schema1 | typeof schema2) ?

Comment: Wow! Was it really that simple?! That actually works. I guess I was making things a lot more complex than they need to be

Comment: it's happens, ... an external eye. Happy to help.

Comment: If you want, write that as an actual answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, that could be the trick for you.

```
function someFunc(parameter1: any, schema: typeof schema1 | typeof schema2) {...}
```

You can also (I suppose) create a dedicated type :

```
type typeForSomeFunc = typeof schema1 | typeof schema2;
function someFunc(parameter1: any, schema: typeForSomeFunc) {...}
```